# Make a layout apply to all SDK<11?

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm using some layout files (default folder) that cannot be used in SDK < 11. I found that I can create a folder "layout-v10" etc, and place special layout files there.

I now want to make these files API 7 compatible. And likewise be used by all API 7-10.
Do I have to create a new single folder for every api layout? Or how can I match every api that is below a specific to the alternative layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can match every API **above** a specific version. For instance, you can have a `layout-v7` folder and a `layout-v11` folder. APIs 7 through 10 would use the resources from the first folder, APIs 11 and above from the later one. Pre API 7 versions would use the resources from the default `layout` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the logic: put the pre-11 layouts in res/layout and put the 11+ versions of the layouts in res/layout-v11.